# How to check if node property is not None while iterating through materials?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

I'm running into a no attribute error while iterating through nodes and nodegroups in some blend files.

Error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

How would I check if objects has no 'name' property and skip it?

```
   for mat in bpy.data.materials:
        if mat.use_nodes == True:
            for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
                #check if no has attribute name
                if node.type in ["GROUP"] and node.node_tree.name == 'NodeGroupName':
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107534/how-to-catch-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something#29112061

Comment: I got rid of 'name' attribute error with:
`if hasattr(node.node_tree, name) == True:`
but it still throws up error over 'node_tree' attribute
`if hasattr(node, node_tree) == True:`
Doesn't work with error: NameError: name 'node_tree' is not defined

Comment: Put 'node_tree' in quotes. if hasattr(node, 'node_tree') == True:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An attribute can be `None`**

The error `NoneType has no attribute` is a common error seen in blender scripting .  For example it can be the case that `context.object is None`

To the OP would recommend editing the title of question to reflect this error message more-so.

> `Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`

thrown by `node.node_tree.name == 'NodeGroupName'`  is informing  `node.node_tree` has the value `None`.  Can test for this being the case, *ie*

```
if node.node_tree is  None:
```

as opposed to

```
if hasattr(node, "node_tree"):
```

Both will be true when the node tree is `None`

It is actually a strange case that the code in question would throw this error, as I'm not aware (yet) of how to add a group node and have no linked node_tree.  Speculate this is the result of deleting a node group from `bpy.data.node_groups` that was a node of a material node tree..

hence the last line of question script could be

```
if (node.type in ["GROUP"]  
        and node.node_tree 
        and node.node_tree.name == 'NodeGroupName'
        ):
```

since chaining ands ceases on first `False`

**Using `getattr`**

Since we pretty much would treat either the same using get attribute with the third argument default

```
node_tree = getattr(node, "node_tree", None)
```

will be `None` in both cases.  IMO this "trumps" using both the has node tree then has name attribute test.  *`None` has nothing, if we know it's none testing further for attributes would seem superfluous*  Can also ensure that if  a node tree is not `None` it **will have a name**. `bpy.types.ShaderNodeTree.name`

**Test script**

Using the above with the "double test" for a node being of `'GROUP'` type check it has a non none node tree.

Make a dictionary, with keys matching node group name containing a list of material name , node name tupples.

```
import bpy
from bpy import data
from collections import defaultdict

# all the group nodes in blendfile
print(data.node_groups.keys())
    
group_nodes = defaultdict(list)
# create a look up dictionary 
for m in data.materials:
    if m.use_nodes:
        for n in m.node_tree.nodes:
            nt = getattr(n, "node_tree", None)
            if nt and n.type == 'GROUP':
                group_nodes[nt.name].append((m.name, n.name))
                
print(group_nodes)
```

**Output.**

File with 1 node group "Test_Material", 2 materials "TestMat" and "TestMat.001".

The node group is used in both materials with name "Group" in both.

```
['Test_Material']

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Test_Material': [('TestMat', 'Group'), ('TestMat.001', 'Group')]})
```

**Notes:**

Beware of equating to `True` or `False` in tests.  By default python  equates most types to True or false. Some examples of false are `None`, the integer `0` and an empty list `[]`

Methods like `hasattr` return either `True` or `False`

```
if hasattr(foo, "bar") == True:
```

if `foo.bar`  exists this reads somewhat akin to

```
if True == True:
```

instead simply use

```
if hasattr(foo, "bar"):
```

Changing above slightly to return boolean false instead of none when the node has no node_tree attribute, `if nt:` will be false in both cases, but we can discern between the two.

```
        nt = getattr(n, "node_tree", False)
        if nt and n.type == 'GROUP':
            group_nodes[nt.name].append((m.name, n.name))
        if nt is None:
            print(f"{m.name}:{n.name} node_tree is None")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ron Jensens comment:

```
    for mat in bpy.data.materials:
        if mat.use_nodes == True:
            for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
                if hasattr(node, 'node_tree') == True:
                    if hasattr(node.node_tree, 'name') == True:
                        if node.type in ["GROUP"] and node.node_tree.name == 'NodeGroupName':
```

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111972/discussion-on-answer-by-0451-how-to-check-if-node-property-is-not-none-while-ite).